# Circe and Scala's Enumeration type

Tags: json, scala, circe

I'm trying to wrap my head around Circe.

So, here's the model I've been given:

```
object Gender extends Enumeration {
     type Gender = Value
     val Male, Female, Unisex, Unknown = Value
}

case class Product(id: String, gender: Gender.Value)
```

I want to

a) encode the following example as JSON

```
        val product = Product(id = "1234", gender = Gender.Female)
```

b) map the resulting JSON back onto the Product case class.

---

My own attempt didn't get me far:

```
  object JsonProtocol {
      implicit val productDecoder: Decoder[Product] = deriveDecoder
      implicit val productEncoder: Encoder[Product] = deriveEncoder
  }
```

result is a compile time error

```
   Error:(52, 49) could not find Lazy implicit value of type io.circe.generic.decoding.DerivedDecoder[A]
   implicit val productDecoder: Decoder[Product] = deriveDecoder
                                            ^
```

I've no idea why this exception is thrown and what the solution could look like. Maybe it's the usage of the Enumeration type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The accepted answer is deprecated (**circe 0.12.0**).

Circe provides now these functions:

```
Decoder.decodeEnumeration[E <: Enumeration](enum: E)
Encoder.encodeEnumeration[E <: Enumeration](enum: E)
```

With the example:

```
implicit val genderDecoder: Decoder[Gender.Value] = Decoder.decodeEnumeration(Gender)
implicit val genderEncoder: Encoder[Gender.Value] = Encoder.encodeEnumeration(Gender)
```

Comment: thx. This works nicely for Scala 2; but unfortunately I've experienced problems with Cross Compile to Scala 3 in https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/2006

Comment: That is correct - I added an answer on how I do it with Scala 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73089261/2750966

Answer (score 15):

Try defining your own encoders and decoders for the enum using:

```
Decoder.enumDecoder[E <: Enumeration](enum: E)
Encoder.enumEncoder[E <: Enumeration](enum: E)
```

something like:

```
object JsonProtocol {
  implicit val genderDecoder: Decoder[Gender.Value] = Decoder.enumDecoder(Gender)
  implicit val genderEncoder: Encoder[Gender.Value] = Encoder.enumEncoder(Gender)
  implicit val productDecoder: Decoder[Product] = deriveDecoder
  implicit val productEncoder: Encoder[Product] = deriveEncoder
}
```

These are needed because the automatic/semiautomatic derivers only work for hierarchies of `sealed trait`s and `case classes` as far as I know. The reason you see that error is because the derived codecs for `Product` will implicitly require encoders/decoders for the types of each of it's parameters. An encoder/decoder for `String` is a standard part of Circe, but you'll probably need to create ones for your own enumerations.

Comment: As of circe 0.12.0 enumEncoder/enumDecoder are deprecated in favor of encodeEnumeration/decodeEnumeration

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum#circe) if you want to use enumerations with circe. You could then try something like this:

```
import enumeratum._

sealed trait Gender extends EnumEntry

case object Gender extends CirceEnum[Gender] with Enum[Gender] {

  case object Male extends Gender
  case object Female extends Gender
  case object Unisex extends Gender
  case object Unknown extends Gender

  val values = findValues
}

Gender.values.foreach { gender =>
    assert(gender.asJson == Json.fromString(gender.entryName))
}
```

This should work with circe's automatic derivation for use with your case classes.

Answer (score 3):

For ***Scala 3*** there is now a solution since version 0.14.5 within ***Circe***.

There is a great Blog explaining this: https://scalajobs.com/blog/enum-serialization-in-scala/

The code from the blog:

```
import io.circe.Codec
import io.circe.derivation.Configuration

given Configuration = Configuration.default
    .withDiscriminator("type")
    .withTransformConstructorNames(_.toUpperCase)​
enum Role {
  case Reader(subscription: Subscription)
  case Editor(profileBio: String, favoriteFont: String)
  case Admin
}
object Role {    ​
  given Codec[Role] = Codec.AsObject.derivedConfigured
}
```

This creates:

```
{"type":"TESTER","subscription":"GENESIS"}
```

If you just have **simple Enums** you can use the following:

```
import io.circe.derivation.{Configuration, ConfiguredEnumCodec}

given Configuration = Configuration.default
enum TestOverrideType derives ConfiguredEnumCodec:
  case Exists, NotExists, IsEquals, HasSize
```

This creates:

```
"NotExists"
```

Thanks for the help of [Lasering](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/11qzd5w/comment/jcq56jh/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

***My earlier answer:***

For ***Scala 3*** there is no solution today within ***Circe***.

However there is a library that works nicely: [circe-tagged-adt-codec](https://github.com/abdolence/circe-tagged-adt-codec)

Here an example that works for me (the rest I do with semiautomatic derivation from Circe):

```
enum TestOverrideType derives JsonTaggedAdt.PureEncoder:
  case Exists, NotExists, IsEquals, HasSize
```