# Automatic derivation of Enumeration can't find Encoder

Tags: scala, enums, circe

I have a case class like this:

```scala
case class Admin(name: String, role: Role)
```

`Role` is an Enumeration

```scala
object Role extends Enumeration {
  type Role = Value
  val Manager = Value
}
```

When I try to:

```scala
import io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.syntax._

val response = Admin("John", Role.Manager).asJson.noSpaces
```

**I get the implicit Encoder not found error.**

```
not enough arguments for method asJson: (implicit encoder: io.circe.Encoder[Admin])io.circe.Json. Unspecified value parameter encoder.
```

I suppose this error is due Enumeration, so I changed to:

```scala
trait Role

object Role {
  object Manager extends Role
}
```

But this does't work too.

Lastly, I tried:

```
trait Role

object Manager extends Role
```

And no success. Can someone help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[enumeratum-circe](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum#circe) enables the following syntax

```
object CirceEnumeratumExample extends App {
  import enumeratum._
  import io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.syntax._

  sealed trait Role extends EnumEntry
  case object Role extends Enum[Role] with CirceEnum[Role] {
    case object Manager  extends Role
    case object User extends Role
    val values = findValues
  }

  case class Admin(name: String, role: Role)
  val response = Admin("John", Role.Manager).asJson.noSpaces
  println(response)
}
```

which outputs

```
{"name":"John","role":"Manager"}
```

where

```
libraryDependencies += "com.beachape" %% "enumeratum" % "1.5.13",
libraryDependencies += "com.beachape" %% "enumeratum-circe" % "1.5.21"
```

Comment: why do I have to install a whole library for a simple task of enum to json in circe?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this question now, you don't *have* to use enumeratum, although it is probably your best bet in a large codebase.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66967469/4981237) explains, [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) supports semi-automatic derivation of enum encoders out of the box.

I found circe -- through circe-generics -- was also able to derive encoders for abstract data types, but the results were surprising:

```scala
import io.circe.generic.auto._

sealed trait Role

object Role {
  case object Manager extends Role
  case object IC extends Role
}

Role.Manager.asJson.toString // "{}"

Employee("John", Role.Manager)
  .asJson
  .toString // "{"name": "John", "role": {"Manager": {}}}"
```

I suspect shapeless, an underlying dependency of circe, treats `object`s as [product types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) with a zero-parameter list.

It is possible to quickly write an `Encoder` instance for `Role` with semi-automatic derivation. Use `Encoder[String]` to summon an existing encoder, then transform `Role` into a `String`:

```scala
implicit val encoder: Encoder[Role] = 
  Encoder[String].contramap {
    case Manager => "Manager"
    case IC => "IC"
  }
```